# How to disable onclick for my link after opening a window and enabling it after the window gets closed?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a link and I was wondering if there was javascript available to make the link only click-able once.

The `onclick` I have just now is :

```
javascript:writeBookmark(this); var newwin = window.open('<c:url value="/buyers/select/addPQQSection.html?listId=${listId}&questionIndex=0&pageId=${pageId}&sectionId=-1&amp;mode=${PQQ_ADD_SECTION }"/>', 'additional', 'width=400,height=280,toolbar=no,,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizeable=no'); newwin.focus(); return null;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

---

EDIT (based on comments):

Using `this.onclick = null` works but then I need to refresh the page to enable the click on my link. I need to disable the click when the window is opened and enable it once the window gets closed.

Comment: add `this.onclick = null;` to the end?

Comment: There is no reason to have `javascript:"` in onclick

Comment: You **should not** repost the same question several times. Instead, wait for an answer that solves your problem and accept it. Do not accept an answer that you don't understand or that doesn't solve your question.

Comment: "add this.onclick = null; to the end" Works is there a way for it to remain null for a few seconds then functionality resumes?

Comment: So your question is not about making the link clickable just once but disabling it until the user closes the opened window...

Comment: Yeah sorry im new to this i did not mean to accept the answer in the previous question.  Basically i want javascript to stop users double clicking and submitting the for numerous times, so null works but then it nulls it until the page is refreshed.  This is why i was wondering if there was an easy addition to the answer to allow for it to remain null for a few seconds to deal with double clicks.

Comment: Edited your question accordingly to your needs. Note that it is way better to explain the whole problem instead talking some parts of it. Also, since you're a programmer, you should speak in programmer terms, not in end user terms.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. The easiest is probably to just hide the button at the end of your script.

Here's what your button could look like:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Once" onclick="runAction(this, '<c:url .... />');" />
```

Then you can have your javascript function (or all this could be inline if you want):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function runAction(element, url) {
  writeBookmark(this); 
  var newwin = window.open(url, 'additional',
     'width=400,height=280,toolbar=no,,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizeable=no'); 
  newwin.focus(); 
  element.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

You could also just disable the button:

```
element.disabled = 'disabled';
```

JQuery makes removing the button a more elegant action:

```
$(element).hide(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href='runMyFunction()'>link</a>`

Then in your Javascript:

```
var check = true; 
function runMyFunction(){ 
    if (check) {
        //do something 
        console.log('run me once');
        check = false;
    }
}
```

Check out my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D28Lc/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `this.onclick = null` add the end of your function call:

```
<a onclick="javascript:writeBookmark(this); var newwin .... this.onclick = null;">click</a>
```

Comment: this.onclick = null; to the end works is there a way for it to remain null for a few seconds then functionality resumes? just so the button looses functionality for a few seconds?

Comment: You could create a function and add a setTimeout to it. But best way then would be to add a variable instead of removing the onclick